# Is it really possible to "catch 'em all"?

Tags: pokemon-series

Since there are now 649 Pokemon, is it really possible to legitimately catch every single Pokemon from all the generations on one game? Black/White are only limited to 8 boxes on the PC and I don't know if that changes in Black 2/White 2 to hold more. Since you can't trade B/W pokemon back to other generations, it looks like these games would be the only ones you could try to get them all on.

Comment: You get 24 boxes in B/W. You start with 8, but more are added as you start to fill those up.

Comment: Can you acquire pokemon from all other generations in B/W?

Comment: All other generation can be imported into B/W via 2 Nintendo DS. It's a legitimate question so I don't see why it would be closed?

Comment: I don't see how this is close-worthy at all. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: It's good question, I don't know if it's possible to hold all the pokemon in a single game anymore.

Comment: Catching them all and holding them all are different things though. I can catch Shinx and have it evolve into Luxio then Luxray and have caught all three of them while only holding one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "catching 'em all *on one game*."  Obviously, during a playthrough of a single game, you cannot catch a wild individual from every single species; for one thing, the games are designed such that some Pokémon cannot be obtained without trading them from another version.  However, via trades and transferring from previous generations, you can gather all Pokémon other than:

- [Mew](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Celebi](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celebi_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Jirachi](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Jirachi_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Deoxys](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Deoxys_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Phione](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Phione_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Manaphy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Manaphy_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Darkrai](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Darkrai_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Shaymin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shaymin_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Arceus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arceus_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Victini](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Victini_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Zorua](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zorua_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Zoroark](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zoroark_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Keldeo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Keldeo_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Meloetta](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Meloetta_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Genesect](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Genesect_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

in a single game, and with events (either by participating in them or just getting the Pokémon from others in trades) you can get everything other than Meloetta and Genesect, which have not been released in any events yet.  You can gain enough boxes to hold them all by putting at least one Pokémon in each box and then exiting & reentering the storage system until you've unlocked all 24 boxes.

Comment: So is the answer really *Not at this time*?  Like Mew, there's no way to obtain Meloetta or Genesect in the games themselves.  But unlike Mew there hasn't been release event for them.  In theory, nobody should have these two pokemon?

Comment: @hydroparadise: Actually, upon further research, I am incorrect: it appears that they are giving away both [Meloetta](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Japanese_Nintendo_event_Pokémon_in_2012#Movie_Meloetta) and [Genesect](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/CoroCoro_August_issue_reveals_%27Genesect%27) in Japan *right now*.

Comment: Ignoring event Pokemon and assuming you had enough consoles to trade and transfer with yourself, which games would you need to get them all?

Comment: Please note that since posting, this answer have been obsoleted, since events have distributed the missing pokemons:
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Meloetta_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#In_events
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Genesect_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#In_events

Comment: @challen interesting question, you could figure it out from the information on bulbapedia but it would be quite a slog (nowhere near as big a slog as actually collecting them all mind you)

Comment: @challen, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138986/which-pokemon-games-do-i-need-to-have-in-order-to-catch-them-all?rq=1 it looks like the answer is that X, Y, OR and OS are sufficient.

Comment: Meloetta and Genesect are now available through events (2016)

Comment: By doing some Glitches in Pokemon red/blue released on the 3ds you can get mew  since they didn't change the code in those game to remove the glitches.

Answer (score 15):

It is entirely possible to catch 'em all. You will need to do a lot of trading, and it may prove difficult to get hold of the Nintendo event Pokemon, especially the ones which haven't been distributed in years like Mew. There are resources online such as http://www.pokebay.com/ where you can source the Pokemon you need to complete your collection.

Good luck to complete your collection!

Comment: I did not know about pokebay, thanks for that reference! :)

Comment: You cannot catch them all. Arceus (hope I spelled that right) is unobtainable through legit gameplay.