# Which Pokemon games do I need to have in order to 'Catch them All'?

Tags: pokemon-series

In Pokemon Blue/Red there is 11 exclusive non obtainable Pokemons so there are 151 (number of Pokemons) - 11 = 140 Pokemon possible to acquire in each version.

So in which Pokemon series is the amount of Pokemon possible to catch the highest? I'm curious which Pokemon game combinations (Red/Crystal/Black 2/Y) are needed to have all full global Pokedex.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @iber Do you mean for the first generation? The current generation? *All* generations?

Comment: @iber If you mean in all generations, this question is an unbounded list.  It will keep growing with every new game, not to mention changing trade mechanics will cause problems.  These types of questions don't work well for the site.  If you limit the scope to, say, as of gen 6, that is much more manageable.

Comment: All generations. I'm asking now about situation after X & Y. Yes I know that it will change with new game. The question about only one generation don't have any value if your aim is have full *full* Pokedex.

Comment: @iber, OrigamiRobot is suggesting you limit the scope to "all games up to gen 6", so that the answer can be completely true and continue to be true when gen 7 comes out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Obtaining a full Pokédex tends to be less about how many types of Pokémon are available in each game (and for the record, X/Y now seem to hold the record for most *natively available* Pokémon), and more about the legendaries. Particularly now that in generation 6, the GTS will allow you to search for Pokémon that you have not yet seen. Also, keep in mind that there are varying degrees of "full" when it comes to the Pokédex, because there are 11 'known' event only Pokémon held hostage by the whims of Gamefreak/Nintendo (Gen6 adds 2-3 more to this count).

### Emerald

Before embarking on the adventure, it is recommended to restart a couple of times in order to transfer two of the starters to Generation 4, leaving the third and final one to be transferred with the legendaries and various other Pokémon after you complete the adventure. Yes, this means you should have unlocked the Pal Park in a gen 4 game prior to starting. Otherwise be prepared to transfer the legendaries and then restart to get the starters. But getting the starters out of the way first means that should you discover your Pokédex missing some non-legendary gen3 Pokémon, zipping around Hoenn to grab them with the game already completed is a breeze.

Emerald is practically required for the generation 3 legendaries, as you have access to both [Groudon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Groudon_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and [Kyogre](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kyogre_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) (although Heartgold/Soulsilver blunt this requirement a bit). Pick up [the](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Regirock_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) [three](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Regice_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) [Regi](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Registeel_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)'s, and when your mom asks for confirmation on which she saw ([Latias](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Latias_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) or [Latios](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Latios_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)), your answer should depend on which generation 2 remake you have; choose to have Latios roam Hoenn if you plan to get/have HeartGold, Latias if you're getting/have SoulSilver.

### Diamond/Pearl/Platinum

On the face of it, Platinum is probably the superior choice given that it has both [Dialga](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dialga_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and [Palkia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Palkia_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) in one game. *However*, to my knowledge the Wii downloadable title "My Pokémon Ranch" has never received the platinum update outside of Japan, so there goes one chance at obtaining an otherwise event-only [Mew](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and semi-legendary [Phione](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Phione_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29). If you're lucky though, In Diamond/Pearl they do show you the other version's legendary, meaning you could theoretically look it up on the GTS. Finding a non-stupid trade offer this late in the game's life cycle is problematic, however.

Otherwise, after you've transferred things from Emerald, [Regigigas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Regigigas_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) becomes available, and regardless of which of the three games you have; [Azelf](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Azelf_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Mesprit](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mesprit_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Uxie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Uxie_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Girantina](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Giratina_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Heatran](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Heatran_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), and [Cresselia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cresselia_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) are all available.

Additionally if you have the side game Pokemon Ranger (Fiore/Almia/Oblivia) completing it can net you a [Manaphy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Manaphy_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) egg by connecting to any of the Gen4 games. Manaphy can bred with a Ditto for a Phione egg.

### HeartGold/SoulSilver

If you didn't start this process owning one of these games, and you've already done Emerald, which of these two you get may depend on which of the Latias/Latios pair you have. (Again, if you have Latias get SoulSilver, If you have Latios get HeartGold) In an ideal world you'd have two DS systems available, start both your D/P/Pt and HG/SS games at the same time and reset one of the games a few times transferring two starters to one game, get the final starter, transfer all the starters to that game and reset the second game a bunch of times, netting you all 6 generation 2 and 4 starters. Transferring up to Generation 5 and re-starting is also a viable option.

As far as Legendaries go; the second generation legendaries [Ho-Oh](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ho-Oh_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Lugia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lugia_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Suicune](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Suicune_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Entei](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Entei_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), and [Raikou](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Raikou_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) are all available at various points in both games. First generation legendaries [Articuno](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Articuno_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Zapdos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zapdos_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Moltres](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moltres_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), and [Mewtwo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mewtwo_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) should all be available after beating the Elite Four and exploring the Kanto region.

### Black/White/Black2/White2

I have little to no experience with B2/W2, but from what I've seen, some legendaries are considerably easier to obtain; particularly if you have the 3DS app Pokemon Dream Radar. In any case [Reshiram](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Reshiram_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and [Zekrom](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zekrom_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) are the game exclusive legendaries that will require trading (or use of the GTS) to obtain the other. Other legendaries available for this generation; [Kyurem](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kyurem_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Cobalion](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cobalion_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Terrakion](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Terrakion_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Virizion](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Virizion_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Tornadus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tornadus_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), [Thundurus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Thundurus_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29), and [Landorus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Landorus_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)

You *should* only need one of these four games, with Emerald, Generation 4, and the generation 2 remakes, and perhaps a little use of the GTS, you should be able to complete the entire national Pokédex as of Generation 5 with the likely exception of most of the event only distribution legendaries (Mew, Celebi, Jirachi, Deoxys, Darkrai, Shaymin, Arceus, Keldeo, Meloetta, Genesect). Which Prepares us for...

### X and Y

As mentioned at the begining of this answer, the improved GTS simplifies things greatly. Any pokemon that exists withing X&Y can easily be found on it - and improved filters mean you can show only 'non-special' Pokémon requests, and you can even filter the results by requests that you can actually fill. While this also means you can search for legendaries you need to fill your Pokédex, good luck with that one. While some people do post reasonable requests, those are largely a rarity compared to the plethora of impossible to fill ones. Like a lvl 1-10 Charizard.

Another option for assisting your Pokedex filling is Wonder Trading. While you have no say in what you get, sometimes you can get rather rare stuff like Larvesta or Togepi - people often dump their extra pokemon from breeding into Wonder Trade. As an added bonus, it's a great way to collect ID numbers for the daily lottery.

[Xerneas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Xerneas_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and [Yveltal](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yveltal_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) are the two game exclusive legendary Pokémon this time around, with [Zygarde](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zygarde_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) being shared. Also available late game are the one of the Kanto region legendary birds (which one depends on your starter) and Mewtwo (Although they could have been obtained in the Gen2 remakes). After transferring from generation 5 with the [Pokemon Bank 3DS app](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134200/how-do-i-transfer-previous-generation-pok%C3%A9mon-to-x-y), your pokedex should be complete. Also there are reports of likely suspects for distribution-only Hoopa, Volcanion, and Diancie.

---

### Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire

The release of the Gen 3 remakes causes the lion's share of the above to be largely obsolete. All that is required now is one of X/Y and one of OR/AS. There has since been another question; [Can I complete my pokedex only with 6th gen games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/193499/30115), to which my researched answer was ***yes***. This 'yes' does have the stipulation that there are still version-locked Pokemon for both sets of games, so unless you buy all four, some online trading through the GTS may be unnavoidable. However, between X/Y and OR/AS, all starter Pokemon, all regular Pokemon, and all (non-mythic-)legendary Pokemon that count towards the completion of your Pokedex can be caught. Even the previously event-only Deoxys is now natively available in these two games.

Comment: Sir, You are amazing.

Comment: So in conclusion - even with restarting games (Emerald, Y/X, B/W and others) few times without this 11 event-hostages it is impossible to have all Pokedex compleated legaly. This sucks.

Comment: Do note, however, that unless things have changed since B/W; the event-only pokemon do not count against your completion of the Pokédex as far as the in-game assessment by the professor goes. There's just some annoying holes in your pokedex. Holes that annoy the crap out of the OCD which started you down this path in the first place.

Comment: Confirming that. While there are 718 (actually 721 if you count the new "secret" Pokémon) Pokémon on the National Dex, 705 are needed for completion according to the official X/Y Pokédex (That book-like thing). That's all but Mew, Celebi, Phione, Manaphy, Jirachi, Deoxys, Darkrai, Shaymin, Arceus, Keldeo Meloetta, Genesect and a last one I can't seem to remember... And of course Hoopa, Volcanion and Diancie are also not necessary.

Comment: Just commenting here to say that it would be awesome if you could update this answer now that ORAS has been released.  Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @JHixson Aaand done. OR/AS simplifies the process greatly. I hadn't thought to update the answer until you commented, but it could save people from buying a whole bunch of old Pokemon games (not that playing the older games is a bad thing, mind you) and forcing them to jump through a bunch of hoops to get things transferred, so I updated.

Comment: Some time passing sure helps memory. I just reread the comment and remembered which one was missing from my previous list: Victini. Although I'm not sure whether Deoxys was added to the official completion list, so as of ORAS, you might need 706 for completion including Deoxys.

Comment: This really deserves a note about how there's an ongoing event this entire year (2016) where every month The Pokemon Company is giving away a different one of the super rare legendaries every month. As it is right now, you have 3 days to claim your Celebi on X/Y/AS/OR (you can claim one in each game you own). Unfortunately, Mew is gone as it was a February give away. http://www.pokemon20.com/en-us/mythical.html