# Can I complete the Pokedex with only 6th Generation games?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I just bought Pokemon Alpha Sapphire for myself and Omega Ruby for my friend. I also played the X/Y games and I have Pokebank. The problem is: I didn't play games of the 5th and 4th generation. I basically skipped the Nintendo DS games and started playing again with the release of Pokemon X/Y.

My question is: Is it possible to complete the Pokedex with **only** the four 6th Gen games (X, Y, Omega Ruby, Alpha Sapphire)? Or will there be some unobtainable Pokemon?

I'm not talking about the rare legendary ones like Celebi, Arceus etc. I just want to know whether I need to use a 5th gen game or not to "Catch 'Em All".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Researching the answer to this question, I encountered two extremely helpful lists on Serebii.net:

- [Pokémon X & Pokémon Y - Unobtainable Pokémon](http://www.serebii.net/xy/unobtainable.shtml)
- [Pokémon Omega Ruby & Pokémon Alpha Sapphire - Unobtainable Pokémon](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/unobtainable.shtml)

Diligently comparing the two lists, the *only* Pokémon that appear on both are mythic legendairies such as Mew, Celebi, etc. Even all the generation-2/4/5 legendaries like Suicune, Cresselia, and Landorus (to name one from each) are available in the Gen3 remakes (many are, of course, gated to one version or the other).

So, assuming the lists are accurate (and they appear to be); **Yes, the pokédex is complete-able owning only Gen6 games.** Keeping in mind that as soon as the PokéBank was released last February, this was already possible through the GTS - I mean, unless you own all four games, some trading is unavoidable due to how Pokémon games are structured.

Comment: I don't understand, you say there are unobtainable pokemon, but then you say the answer is yes?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Mythical Rare Legendaries, the ones that are distributed only by the whims of Nintendo (Mew, Celebi, Arceus, Diancie, etc...), and are comparatively rarely distributed outside of Japan. Those do not technically count towards the completion of the Pokedex as far as in-game rewards for completing the Pokedex are concerned, and the question specifically mentions ***"I'm not talking about the rare legendary ones like Celebi, Arceus etc."***.

Comment: For reference, there are 12 or so Mythical Legendary Pokemon, and Nintendo released 6 of them in Japan and 2 of **those** to the *rest of the world* in 2014. Owning any other games outside of Gen6 does not grant access to these Pokemon, and at the current rate, it will take 2-6 years to *officially* obtain them if you are starting out now.

Comment: As an update to this, 2016 is the 20th anniversary of Pokemon and Nintendo has been giving away all of the unobtainable Pokemon:  http://www.pokemon20.com/en-us/mythical.html

Answer (score 6):

For Science -

I went ahead and performed an intersection of the unobtainable sets of pokemon in both the game versions from here:

**Pokemon XY** - http://www.serebii.net/xy/unobtainable.shtml

**Pokemon ORAS** - http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/unobtainable.shtml

The list is as follows :

1. *#151* - **Mew**
2. *#251* - **Celebi** (Obtainable as a gift for depositing/withdrawing a pokemon in pokemon bank. Worked even with the trial period.)
3. *#385* - **Jirachi**
4. *#489* - **Phione**
5. *#490* - **Manaphy**
6. *#491* - **Darkrai**
7. *#492* - **Shaymin**
8. *#493* - **Arceus**
9. *#494* - **Victini**
10. *#647* - **Keldeo**
11. *#648* - **Meloetta**
12. *#649* - **Genesect**

Everything else is obtainable from the base games without a requirement to trade in from previous generation games.

Answer (score -2):

They said EVERY pokemon would be obtainable within those two sets of games, quoting them at all 719 so as the new generations of players who may not have had a DS or previous hardware would be able to start anew and have the possibility of completing the pokedex without all that hassle.  In a sense they were attempting to continue driving up sales of X & Y while also presenting two more nostalgic titles to bring a close to the quartet of games.

Comment: ORAS was also a long-time community wish. Also, "every" probably means "every Pokemon needed to officially complete the Pokedex in game", which is currently a count of 705. Actually, 706 are technically obtainable due to Deoxys being part of the main storyline, which was previously exclusively obtainable through special event downloads. Celebi(, Jirachi) and Diancie have also been made available since X/Y's release, so if someone started back then, they have access to 708-709 Pokemon barring trades.