# Between Pokemon X/Y/ORAS, can the pokedex be completed?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

If I were to have all four games, could the pokedex be completed? Excluding the event mons, of course.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/193499/58396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, and probably without transfers.

Actually, you can catch most of the legendaries once you get the eon flute and fly to various locations on your latios/latias marked either by red lights or disturbances in the sky.  I have already seen mesperit and Terrakion myself, and have seen Palkia, Dialga, ho-oh, lugia,  and Zekrom in Trailers.  Besides event legendaries, you can catch most pokemon.  The real question is if you can get pokemon that were transfer only in x and y like purugly and meowth.  According to serebii.net these pokemon can be found in the mirage forest and mirage island available with a little exploration and some HMs.  This game seems like one of Game Freaks completion games with move tutors and hidden abilities not previously available, I would be surprised if you could not catch all of the pokemon.

Answer (score -3):

Yes and No.

**Yes** if you have the pokemon that you need from older games that are un obtainable in RSXY, obtainable through other people or transfering from older games.

**No** if you can't get pokemon such as Palkia, Dialga, Deoxys, the Regis, so on and so forth then probably not

Comment: Dialga & Palkia & the Regis  are available in ORAS.

Comment: Well, Deoxys is actually available during the postgame, and the regis are native to ORAS. Palkia/Dialga are catchable in some circumstances too.

Comment: This is out and out false. You can catch Palkia, Dialga, Deoxys, and each of the Regis (including Regigigas). And there is not a single Pokemon that needs to be transferred from a previous generation in order to be obtained in ORAS, other than event Pokemon for which there hasn't yet been a distribution in 6th gen.